# rxjs version error while running npm install

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I was working on a new Angular App. I created that using Angular CLI with `ng new.`

When I tried to lauch that app using npm start , I got following error :

```
ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,74): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,77): error TS1109: Expression expected.
```

I inspected the dependencies using `ng -version` inside that project and found below output.

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cdk                      7.2.1
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/material                 7.2.1
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

I had another Angular app installed on my machine .

I ran `ng -version` again in this app giving below result.

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Comapring the results , I got below difference

**App Giving error has**

```
rxjs                              6.4.0
```

**And App running fine has**

```
rxjs                              6.3.3
```

I changed the rxjs version in not running app to below in `package.json` like below :

```
"rxjs": "6.3.3"
```

and the problem got resolved

So I have below questions , can anybody please answer these ?

1)I am not able to analyse why downgrading `rxjs version` resolved the issue ? Since all other component versions are the same in both the apps . First app (not running one uses angular material as addition)

2)I had two apps to compare the versions . Had it not been the case , is there any way to find out this error is due to rxjs downgrading of version ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1 & 2 :
Downgrading rxjs version resolved bcz you're using a old compiler version.
Find yours at `package.json` `CTRL+F` `typescript`
Try installing the newest version of typescript:

```
npm install -g typescript@latest.
```

You can also use `npm update` instead of install, without the latest modifier.

Comment: I ran npm install -g typescript@latest , which seems installing latest typescript version (typescript@3.2.4) but when I create new app with ng new , the new app created still has typescript version as "typescript": "~2.7.2" and so issue still exists.

Comment: In order to update the angular-cli package installed globally in your system, you need to run:
`npm uninstall -g angular-cli 


npm cache clean or npm cache verify (if npm > 5)
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` 

Depending on your system, you may need to prefix the above commands with sudo.

Also, most likely you want to also update your local project version, because inside your project directory it will be selected with higher priority than the global one:

rm -rf node_modules
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install